# "Unknown column" error in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT  transaction_user_id, transaction_no, transaction_total_amount, transaction_date, transaction_status FROM OCN.user_transaction WHERE transaction_date >= '949516200' AND transaction_date <= '1391452199' AND transaction_status in(success,inprocess) ORDER BY  transaction_date
```

The error message:

> Invalid SQL:
>   MySQL Error:1054 (Unknown column 'success' in 'where clause')

Actually there in the table a column named transaction_status exists.

Comment: It's looking for a `success` column, though?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you need to change

```
in(success,inprocess)
```

to

```
in('success','inprocess')
```

because string literals must be quoted in SQL

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct

```
transaction_status in(success,inprocess)
```

should be

```
transaction_status in('success','inprocess')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for a status that is a string, but as you have not enclosed the 'options', they are interpreted as a column.

```
transaction_status in(success,inprocess)
```

should be

```
transaction_status in('success','inprocess')
```